# Get almost same string name

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I'm using C# in UWP (Universal Windows Platform).

I have these names:

```
Katy Perry - Last Friday Night  3:50
Taylor Swift - Love Story 3:56
Katy Perry - Roar (How to Train Your Dragon 3 OST) 3:42
Taylor Swift - I Knew You Were Trouble 3:12
Inna - Bad Boys 2:46
Katy Perry feat. Snoop Dog - California Gurls 3:53
Katy Perry Wide Awake 3:41
```

I want to get same names in a collection. for example these items has a key name "Katy Perry"

```
Katy Perry - Last Friday Night  3:50
Katy Perry - Roar (How to Train Your Dragon 3 OST) 3:42
Katy Perry feat. Snoop Dog - California Gurls 3:53
Katy Perry Wide Awake 3:41
```

I want to get these items in a collection.
this is not for "Katy Perry" key, also "Taylor Swift".
Something like this:

```
List for Katy Perry key
Katy Perry - Last Friday Night  3:50
Katy Perry - Roar (How to Train Your Dragon 3 OST) 3:42
Katy Perry feat. Snoop Dog - California Gurls 3:53
Katy Perry Wide Awake 3:41

List for Taylor Swift key
Taylor Swift - Love Story 3:56
Taylor Swift - I Knew You Were Trouble 3:12

Other keys
Inna - Bad Boys 2:46
```

how can I do this?

Comment: Do you already have the list of key names to split them into, or is the code supposed to guess what to use?

Comment: LINQ's groups (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384063.aspx)???

Comment: I don't have key names, these are files that my application will found in Music library, if I know the key names, I could've solve this.

Comment: @Gosha_Fighten thanks, works very well

Comment: @Ramtin Welcome. I've moved this info to an answer so that you can mark it as a solution and close this thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can group your list using grouping in LINQ. See [group clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384063.aspx).